# how to fetch data from NSMutableArray depending upon content within it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am having `NSMutableArray` as below

How can I fetch only those data that have `experience_id=1` or Update those data?

Is there any other way without looping?

```
(
            {
            "exp_achievements" = "get certificate for best employee";
            "exp_achive_id" = 1;
            "experience_id" = 1;
        },
    {
            "exp_achievements" = "get certificate for best employee test";
            "exp_achive_id" = 3;
            "experience_id" = 1;
        },
            {
            "exp_achievements" = test2;
            "exp_achive_id" = 5;
            "experience_id" = 3;
        }
    )
```

Comment: tell me how can you access whole array at a time

Comment: I am having all data at a time and after that want filtered data such as for perticular exprience_id

Comment: @Roshni is this a json string?

Comment: but you have to access a single array object at a time,so you have to use loop

Comment: @Roshni I cant understand the structure of array its like array[0]={string1,string2}; array[1]={e,e} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate to filter collections:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"experience_id"],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"experience_id"], nil];
NSPredicate *f = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"experience_id == 1"];
[a filterUsingPredicate:f];
```

prints :

```
f:(
        {
        "experience_id" = 1;
    }
)
```

If your 'experience_id' value is string, change format to `@"experience_id.intValue == 1"`

Comment: If in your inner dictionary object for key 'experience_id' is number - then it works, tested. If it's string - then predicate format should be "experience_id LIKE[cd] '1'".

Comment: it is number.as you can see in response print in my question. Though it is working fine for `@"exp_achievements == 'test2'"`, but not for exprience_id

Comment: try NSLog that inner dictionary and find out a types of values for keys, i suspect it's string, not number.

Comment: `inner dict : {
    "exp_achievements" = "get certificate for best employee";
    "exp_achive_id" = 1;
    "experience_id" = 1;
}`

Comment: `@"experience_id LIKE [cd] '3'` is working fine.but what in case i want to give some integer value in place of 3 because `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",integerValue]` is not working too

Comment: your value for experience_id key _is_ string, so either use my addition to answer or `LIKE` with `%@` formatter.

Comment: will filtering array, flush main array?

Comment: `filterUsingPredicate` does alter the array, but `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` wont (the latter method is from `NSArray`, so it cannot alter the object).

Answer (score 2):

Try with NSPredicate with value for key experience_id=1 i am not sure but try it may help u

Comment: how can i use nspredicate with nsmutablearray?

Comment: As peter said use nspredicate for filteringarrayusingpredicate   NSPredicate *pre=[NSPredicate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:temp_details];

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` (from `NSArray`), you have to create an `NSPredicate` that filters on your desired key for that. It returns an array with the matching items. There's also `filterUsingPredicate` in `NSMutableArray` that remove items not matching the predicate.